# PuPHPet + Git + SSH + Mysql + Composer

Tags: ssh, module, vagrant, puppet, puphpet

I am using puphpet and I'm running into problems.

What I want is:

1. Restore database backup
2. Clone a repository
3. Run composer

From my understanding of PuPHPet, they download loads of modules and run them based on the config.yaml properties, but what really makes the magic is the puphpet/puppet/manifest.pp
which I don't want to touch, but it seems to be impossible if I wanna make it work.

Among these modules we have the VCSREPO, which is meant to help with clone repos

```
vcsrepo { "/path/to/repo":
  ensure   => latest,
  provider => git,
  source   => 'git://example.com/repo.git',
  revision => 'master',
}
```

https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo

When I tried to do as told on this blog http://livecipher.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/deploy-code-from-git-using-puppet.html it worked but I ran into problems with my SSH keys, which is where I am stuck!!!

I created this module **clone.pp**

```
class bla::clone ($repo) {      
  package { 
    'git': ensure => installed,     
  }      
  vcsrepo { "/var/www/inst/${repo}":         
    ensure   => latest,         
    provider => git,         
    require  => Package["git"],         
    source   => "https://gitlab.d1bi.mobi/go3i/${repo}.git",         
    revision => 'master',     
  } 
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

> The error is ==> default: Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/git clone
>   https://gitlab.d1bi.mobi/go3i/reobi.git /var/www/inst/reobi' returned
>   128: Cloning into '/var/www/inst/reobi'... ==> default: fatal: could
>   not read Username for 'https://gitlab.d1bi.mobi': No such device or
>   address

I would really appreciate if ANYONE could help me, or just give me a hint!

Comment: Thanks for describing the scenario so thoroughly, but what's more important: 1. What have your tried *about your key problem* and 2. what exactly is failing for you?

Comment: Sorry, that was my first post in StackOverflow! Trying to catch up, the way it works...
Anyway, I created this module 

filename clone.pp
`class bla::clone ($repo) {

    package { 'git':
        ensure => installed,
    }

    vcsrepo { "/var/www/instantmobilizer/${repo}":
        ensure   => latest,
        provider => git,
        require  => Package["git"],
        source => "https://gitlab.dotmobi.mobi/gomobi/${repo}.git",
        revision => 'master',
    }
}`

Comment: The error is 
`==> default: Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/git clone https://gitlab.d1bi.mobi/go3i/reobi.git /var/www/inst/reobi' returned 128: Cloning into '/var/www/inst/reobi'...
==> default: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.d1bi.mobi': No such device or address`

@FelixFrank

Comment: No problem! Can you update with your question with the information? It is hard to read in comments. Thanks!

Comment: Is the webserver at https://gitlab.d1bi.mobi/go3i/reobi.git protected using HTTP basic authentication? What happens if you `git clone https://gitlab.d1bi.mobi/go3i/reobi.git /var/www/inst/reobi` manually from the console?